# In tinyMCE apply format to noneditabel areas

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I use tinyMCE with the 'noneditable' plugin.

When I mark some Text including a noneditable area in the tinyMCE-editor and then apply some format to this selection, the format will not be applied  to the 
noneditable fragment.

For example:

I select:

`start Text  <span class="mceNonEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="false">not editable area</span> end text`

and I want to make it bold, the result is:

```
<strong>start Text  </strong><span class="mceNonEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="false">not editable area</span><strong> end text</strong>
```

what I expect and what I need would be the following:

```
<strong>start Text  <span class="mceNonEditable" data-mce-contenteditable="false">not editable area</span> end text</strong>
```

What can I do, to have the noneditable fragments be formatted, too?

(I use tinyMCE 4.1.10)

Comment: I am facing the same problem, using 3.5.10 version.

Comment: I found a workaround. look here: http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=118212#p118212 Does it fit also with version 3.5.10?

Comment: Thanks Gio! It works for 3.5.10 version as well. Cheers!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and your link seems not to work anymore. Could you please post a solution? Thanks

Comment: Such a pity, that the link does not work anymore. I made a change to the file  /tinymce/classes/Formatter.js: I will append my changes as a new answer

Answer (score 2):

I know its a little bit old issue but still popping as one of the first search results of that issue...
we faced the same issue in out team,
we added a non editable text to the content via dropdown select and as happened 
to you 
when we select text range in the editor and try to format if, the non editable element was ignored. 
I solved it by wrapping the non editable content (span element) with another span that is editable, 
now when text range is selected the outer span gets the selected format and affecting the inner span (non editable).

```
<span class="someClass"><span class="mceNonEditable">Non Editable Text</span></span>
```

* the outer element must have the class for the tinymce won't clear it.

Comment: Almost works. Only issue I found is if i then try and drag the element the non-editable element gets dragged out of the surrounding span

Answer (score 1):

The worakaround in the tinymce forum was to manipulate the file:
**/tinymce/classes/Formatter.js**

in the function:

```
function applyRngStyle(rng, bookmark, node_specific)
{

....
                        // Is it valid to wrap this item
                        // TODO: Break this if up, too complex
                        if (contentEditable && !hasContentEditableState && isValid(wrapName, nodeName) && isValid(parentName, wrapName) &&
                                !(!node_specific && node.nodeType === 3 &&
                                node.nodeValue.length === 1 &&
                                node.nodeValue.charCodeAt(0) === 65279) &&
                                !isCaretNode(node) &&
                                (!format.inline || !isBlock(node))) {
                            // Start wrapping
.....

}
```

I had to uncomment the "**contentEditable && !hasContentEditableState**"

```
function applyRngStyle(rng, bookmark, node_specific)
{

....
                        // Is it valid to wrap this item
                        // TODO: Break this if up, too complex
                        // This are the changes that I made:
                        if (/*contentEditable && !hasContentEditableState &&*/ isValid(wrapName, nodeName) && isValid(parentName, wrapName) &&
                                !(!node_specific && node.nodeType === 3 &&
                                node.nodeValue.length === 1 &&
                                node.nodeValue.charCodeAt(0) === 65279) &&
                                !isCaretNode(node) &&
                                (!format.inline || !isBlock(node))) {
                            // Start wrapping
.....

}
```